# The WSMan Provider host process did not return a proper response >> trying to move AD from one server to another

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2022

I am currently in the process of moving an domain controller from one Server > Windows Server 2012R2 to Windows Server 2022.

I am currently working my way through the Active Directory Domain Services Configuration Wizard but an error has appeared.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCRcQ.png)

The WSMan Provider Host Process did not return a proper response.

I have looked online but I can't really see anything for this specific scenario.

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur, when the `MaxMemoryPerShellMB` value on the remote DV (you are using WS-Man or WinRM) is not high enough to allow a proper response to be returned.

To check the current value, run the following on the machine you are trying to retrieve data from (using PowerShell / as Admin):

```
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB
```

The value should be around 2147483647. To set a new value, run the following:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB %NEWVALUE% -Force
```

But WinRM is not needed to promote or demote new/old DC. I would use the good old `dcpromo` tool launched from the Server Manager.